# WordPress Plugin - Table output for page URL listings

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm building my first WordPress plugin which in basic terms is going to grab a list of page URL's and then show them all in a table.

I have all the queries in place that I need and if I output to a basic echo, I get a big long list of all the page URL's on a site which is what it is supposed to do. But, like I said above, I want to output these URL's to a prettier table layout.

I want to create a table with just two headers (Link & Title) and then have the list of URL's underneath the headers.

I'm struggling at the moment to get the output from the query to list correctly in the table. What I am getting is this:

[Existing table layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9irfF.png)

So as you can see, its repeating both the table headers as well as the URL's.

To cut a long story short, can anyone help me in making this table have just the the two headers at the top and then have the list of URLs and titles underneath them for each page.

I'm using a pretty basic function to gather the info I want and then echo'ing the table:

```html
$pages = get_pages( 'post_status=publish' );
foreach ( $pages as $page )
{
    $pagetitle = $page->post_title;
    $pagelink = get_permalink( $page->ID );
    echo "<table style='width:50%'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th align='left'>Link</th>";
    echo "<th align='left'>Title</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='left'>{$pagelink}</td>";
    echo "\n";
    echo "<td align='left'>{$pagetitle}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense and you can understand what I am trying to do! I know that this code probably isn't the best, but its all a learning curve!

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Looks to me like you should have the `table` and first `tr` tags OUTSIDE the foreach loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pages = get_pages( 'post_status=publish' );
echo "<table style='width:50%'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th align='left'>Link</th>";
echo "<th align='left'>Title</th>";
echo "</tr>";

foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $pagetitle = $page->post_title;
    $pagelink = get_permalink( $page->ID );
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='left'>{$pagelink}</td>";
    echo "\n";
        echo "<td align='left'>{$pagetitle}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Is that what you're going for? This will make one table and loop through the pages to create rows, instead of creating a table for each row

Comment: It would look even nicer to replace the echos with straight html

Comment: Perfect! Looks so simple when you see it working, not sure how I missed that! Thanks for help!

Comment: No problem. I agree with @DanielFoust that it would look better without the echos. Just use a `?>` to close your php tags, add your few lines of HTML, and reopen php with `<?php`